# Install SSL certificate for RDP on Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, rdp, windows-terminal-services

I need to configure SSL for RDP, and am following the instructions described here:

http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2007/01/26/Configure-RDP-over-SSL-with-SelfSSL.aspx

My client's server already has a SSL certificate (.cer file), and I attempted to import it so that Terminal Services would recognize it.  The importing instructions I followed are: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816794#3.

Unfortunately, when I click "Edit" from the "RDP-tcp Properties" dialog (for a Terminal Services certificate), no certificate appears.

How can I get the certificate to appear here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816794#3 worked for me... 
...that is from "Import the Certificate into the Local Computer Store" steps:

10: In the left pane of the console, double-click Certificates (Local Computer).
11: Right-click Personal, point to All Tasks, and then click Import
... etc

Previous attempts of double clicking on certificate (.cer) file itself and importing into the Microsoft certificate store (CAPI) didn't work for me - this led to an empty list of certificates to choose from from edit Certificate on the General tab of RDP-Tcp Properties from within Terminal Services Configuration.

Although I imported a certificate requested from an Entrust Certificate Authority (CA) as opposed to a selfSSL certificate this shouldn't make any difference...